# Не получается вывести аватар пользователя в коментариях Django с использованием Ninja shema

Tags: django, django-model

Файл с моделями для постов и коментариев

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from blog.manager import PublishedManeger


class Post(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = "DRAFT", "Draft"
        PUBLISHED = "PUB", "Published"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique_for_date="published")
    body = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")

    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    objects = models.Manager()
    approved = PublishedManeger()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-published"]
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["-published"])]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "blog:post_detail",
            args=[
                self.published.year,
                self.published.month,
                self.published.day,
                self.slug,
            ],
        )


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    body = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["-created"])]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment by {self.user} on {self.post}"
```

Файл с моделью профиля пользователя

```
from django.conf import settings

# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="users/%Y", default="users/default.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s profile"


    @receiver(post_save, sender=user)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=user)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

Файл API.

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.utils.text import slugify
from ninja import Router, Schema, ModelSchema

from account.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from blog.models import Comment, Post

router = Router()


class PostIn(Schema):
    title: str
    body: str


class PostOut(Schema):
    title: str
    slug: str
    body: str
    created: datetime


class CommentIn(Schema):
    post_id: int
    body: str


class ProfileSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["avatar"]


# class ProfileSchema(Schema):
#     avatar: str


class UserOut(Schema):
    id: int
    username: str
    avatar: ProfileSchema


class CommentOut(Schema):
    post_id: int
    body: str
    created: datetime
    user: UserOut


@router.get("/comments/{post_id}", response=list[CommentOut])
def comment_list(request, post_id: int):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    comments = post.comments.select_related("user")
    return comments


@router.post("/comments/", response=CommentOut)
def comment_create(request, payload: CommentIn):
    values = payload.dict()
    values["user_id"] = int(request.user.id)
    comment = Comment.objects.create(**values)
    comment.save()
    return comment


@router.get("/", response=list[PostOut])
def post_list(request):
    return Post.approved.all()


@router.get("/{post_id}", response=PostOut)
def post_detail(request, post_id: int):
    return Post.objects.get(id=post_id)


@router.post("/")
def post_create(request, payload: PostIn):
    values = payload.dict()
    values["author_id"] = int(request.user.id)
    values["slug"] = slugify(values["title"])
    post = Post.objects.create(**values)
    post.save()
    return {"id": post.id}
```

Файл HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  : Читать
{% endblock %} {% block main %}
  <h2 class="main__heading text-4xl">{{ post.title }}</h2>

  <article class="post">
    <p class="post__body text-xl">{{ post.body }}</p>
    <footer class="post__meta mt-4">Published {{ post.published }} by {{ post.author }}
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline btn-secobdary ml-2" href="{% url "blog:post_share"  post.id %}">Share</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

{% comment %} {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
    <h2>{{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}</h2>
  {% endwith %}
  {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment">
      <p class="info">Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.user_id }}
        {{ comment.created }}</p>
      {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <p>There are no comments.</p>
  {% endfor %} {% endcomment %}

  <section class="comments">
    <h2 class="comments__counter mb-10"></h2>
    <div class="comments__content"></div>
  </section>

  {% include "blog/post/comment_form.html" %}
{% endblock %}


{% block js %}
<script>
  function createCommentElement({ body, created, user}) {
    const commentElement = document.createElement("div")
    commentElement.innerHTML = `<div class="comment mb-10">
      <p class="info"><div class="avatar">
        <div class="w-20 rounded-full  mr-5">
          <img src= ${user.avatar} />
         {% comment %}  <img src="https://daisyui.com/images/stock/photo-1534528741775-53994a69daeb.jpg" />  {% endcomment %}
        </div>
        <p> Comment by  ${user.username} ${new Date(created).toLocaleString("ru")} </p>
        ${body}
    </div>`


    return commentElement
  }

  function loadComments() {
    fetch("/api/blog/comments/{{ post.id }}").then(responce => {
      if (!responce.ok) {
        throw new Error("API Error")
      }
      return responce.json()
    }).then(data => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        commentsCounter.textContent = "There are no comments yet..."
      } else {
        commentsCounter.textContent = `There are ${data.length} comments`
      }
      commentsContent.innerHTML = '<div class="comments__content"></div>'
      commentsContent.append(...data.map(createCommentElement))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }


  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formData = newForm.elements
    const post_id = +formData["post_id"].value
    const body = formData["body"].value

    fetch("/api/blog/comments/", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ post_id, body }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then((responce) => {
      if (!responce.ok) {
        throw new Error("API error")
      }
      loadComments()
      formData["body"].value = ""
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }


  const newForm = document.querySelector(".collapse form[method=post]")
  const commentsCounter = document.querySelector(".comments__counter")
  const commentsContent = document.querySelector(".comments__content")

  newForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadComments)
</script>

{% endblock%}
```

Выдает такую ошибку: Field required [type=missing, input_value=<DjangoGetter: <User: testuser2>>, input_type=DjangoGetter]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/missing